# Serialize a java.io.File within a JSON w/ Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I've got a web service (Jersey 2) which returns several DOCX and PDF files. I don't know which is the best way to do that:

1. Return them as Octet-Stream. This is what I had before implementing it as in 2:

   ```
       @GET
       @Path("solicitudUsuario/plantilla")
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
       public Response descargarPlantillaSolicitudUsuario() throws ConfigurationException, URISyntaxException, IOException{
           File plantillaSolicitudUsuario = this.generalService.getPlantillaSolicitudUsuario();
           return Response.ok(plantillaSolicitudUsuario, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + plantillaSolicitudUsuario.getName() + "\"" ).build();
       }
   ```
2. Wrap files within a Json. I'm using Jackson as json provider. This is what I've done so far:

Web service:

```
        @GET
        @Path("solicitudUsuario/plantilla")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response download() throws ConfigurationException, URISyntaxException, IOException{
            File plantillaSolicitudUsuario = this.generalService.getPlantillaSolicitudUsuario();
            FicheroDevolver f = FicheroDevolver.buildAsWord(plantillaSolicitudUsuario);
            String json = mWriter.writeValueAsString(f);
            return Response.ok(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.withCharset("UTF-8")).entity(json).build();
        }
```

Serializer:

```
        public class FicheroSerializer extends JsonSerializer<FicheroDevolver> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(com.ingartek.ws.zendesk_bizkaibus.model.FicheroDevolver value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            InputStream fis = FileUtils.openInputStream(value.getFichero());

            gen.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeFieldName("fichero");
                //gen.writeBinary(fis, (int)value.getFicheroLength());
                gen.writeRawValue(IOUtils.toString(fis, "UTF-8"));

                gen.writeStringField("nombre", value.getNombre());

                gen.writeStringField("mimeType", value.getMimeType());
            gen.writeEndObject();

            fis.close();
        }

        }
```

Data wrapper:

```
            @JsonSerialize(using = FicheroSerializer.class)
            public class FicheroDevolver {

                /*
                 * Atributos
                 */
                private File fichero;
                private String nombre;
                private String mimeType;
```

Which is the best approach?

Comment: Serializing a `java.io.File` only serializes the filename. What exactly is the point?

Comment: @EJP I don't wan't to write the path as a json attribute, what I want is to send the data itself. Then, in the client, decode and serve it. Do you see my point?

Comment: In that case your question is mis-titled. `java.io.File` only represents a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=new-android-book.pdf");
    return response.build();
```

with `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder`

Comment: So you are suggesting using the first approach, aren't you?

Comment: If i were you, i would use first approach.

Comment: Thanks @Art_Rebel. Initially I was doing that. The thing is how to fetch Files using jQuery and JS.

Comment: It isn't, indeed it's another question. This one is to know which approach is the best according to the community. Why voting it negatively?

Comment: I didn't mark your question as not helpful. It was someone else.